# Drupal Non-Admin Toolbar

Tags: authentication, drupal, admin, toolbar

Is there a module I can add a Toolbar on top of the page, like Admin Toolbar but for Authenticated users ? Simple Menu sorta worked, but had way too many bugs. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Administration menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module.

You can turn on the permissions for authenticated users, the panel will only show those links that you approved for authenticated users too. There is also a built-in module called Dashboard that you need to check for authenticated users.

So you turn on these two, and you check those (under Node in permissions) that you want to approve for authenticated users.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ya I use that module right now for administrator account.  The issue is I need different menu items on the toolbar. Can I put  different menus on the administrator toolbar then on the built in toolbar?